# Question about proof of a covering lemma for compact metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

In Dimension Theory by Hurewicz and Wallman, they prove the result

### Theorem:

Suppose $X$ is a compact, separable metric space and $\alpha$ is a finite open covering of $X$. There exists a positive number $\eta$ with the property that every subset of $X$ of diameter less than $\eta$ is entirely contained in some member of $\alpha$.

via the following argument:

### Given Proof:

Otherwise there exist subsets $X_1,X_2,\dots\subset X$ with diameters tending to 0, none of which are contained in a member of $\alpha$. Let $x_i\in X_i$. Since $X$ is compact, i.e., sequentially compact, there exists a cluster point $x$ of $\{x_i\}$ contained in some member $U_0$ of $\alpha$. But $U_0$ is open, meaning $x$ has a positive distance $d$ from $X-U_0$. Hence every $X_i$ of diameter less than $d$ is contained in $U_0$, contrary to our hypothesis.

### My question:

Shouldn't 'every $X_i$ of diameter less than $d$ is contained in $U_0$' be replaced by 'some $X_i$ of diameter less than $d$ is contained in $U_0$?

Comment: Since $U_0$ is open there exists a ball of radius $r$ around $x_0$ contained in $U_0$. Since any set of diameter $\leq r/2$ containing $x_0$ is contained in the ball of radius $r$ which is contained in $U_0$, the result follows.

Comment: @Balajisb I deduced as much for myself. Thank you. I'm wondering, though, isn't it possible that one of the $X_i$ have diameter less than $d$ but are not contained within $U_0$?

Comment: Let $y \in X_i$ and $d(y,x_0) \leq diameter(X_i) \leq r \implies y \in B(x_0,r) \subseteq U_0 \implies y \in U_0 \implies X_i \subseteq U_0$.

Comment: @Balajisb Ahh wonderful, thank you.

Comment: @Balajisb But this only works in the case that $x$, or as you write, $x_0$, is a member of each $X_i$ with diameter $\leq r$, correct? Couldn't it hold that $x_0$ is not a member of some $X_i$ such that $X_i$ has diameter $\leq d$?

Comment: Assumption: There is a sequence of sets $X_1,X_2,.....$ such that $diameter(X_i) \rightarrow 0$ and $X_i$ is not contained in any single member of open cover. Pick arbitarily $x_i \in X_i$. Now $\{x_i\}$ has a convergent subsequence and this limit point is $x_0$. Now there will exist $U_0$ containing $x_0$ and there will be $r$ such that $B(x_0,r) \subseteq U_0$. Now it is assumed that $X_i$ is not completely contained in any set of open cover. But there does exist an $X_i$ such that $x_0 \in X_i$ and $diameter(X_i) \leq r$ but this implies $X_i \subseteq U_0$ which results in a contradiction.

Comment: As mentioned in above comment. Its a proof by contradiction and not by construction or finding the positive number $\eta$.

Comment: By the way, $\eta$ is called Lebesgue number of a given open cover. Also, you don't need to assume that $X$ is separable, any compact metric space is already separable.

Comment: @Jakobian Interesting, thank you for the additional information. I only added the separability condition because the book assumes separable, metric spaces throughout, and I don't believe it includes the result you mention.

Comment: @DerekH. I see, I think that's a decent choice for a book about dimension theory. The three main dimension functions, Lebesgue covering dimension, small and big inductive dimensions, all coincide for separable metric spaces. So this should simplify a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is in general not true that every $X_i$ of diameter less than $d$ is contained in $U_0$. I shall come back to this later.

However, **some** $X_i \subset U_0$ is sufficient to get the desired contradiction to the assumption that no $X_i$ is contained in member of $\alpha$. We even have the stronger conclusion that **infinitely many** $X_i \subset U_0$.

Since $x$ is cluster point of  $\{x_i\}$, the set $I_r = \{ i \mid d(x_i,x) < r\}$ is infinite for each $r > 0$. But in general $J = \{ i \mid x_i \notin U_0\} \ne \emptyset$, and by definition $X_i \not\subset U_0$ for $ \in J$. Given any $r > 0$, there may exist $i \in J$ such that $X_i$ has diameter less than $r$ which shows that their claim is not correct (take $r = d$). This certainly happens if $J$ is infinite.

In general it is not even true that there exists $r > 0$ such that $X_i \subset U_0$ for all $i \in I_r$ such that $X_i$ has diameter less than $d$. We can only say that $X_i \subset U_0$ for $i \in I_{d/2}$ such that $X_i$ has diameter less than $d/2$, but this suffices to finish the proof. In fact, if $i \in I_{d/2}$ such that $X_i$ has diameter less than $d/2$, then for each $y \in X_i$
$$d(y,x) \le d(y,x_i) + d(x_i,x) < d/2 + d/2 = d$$
because $y, x_i \in X_i$. If we allow that $X_i$ has diameter less than $d$, we only get
$$d(y,x) \le d(y,x_i) + d(x_i,x) < d + r$$
where $r > 0$ is arbitrary.